# Tableview doesn't edit on swipe action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the ability to edit the order of the tableview cells in my app. To do this, the user swipes right and taps on an edit button. However, when the edit button is tapped, the tableview doens't begin editing.

Below is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (UIContextualAction, UIView, complete: @ escaping (Bool) -> Void) in

        self.toggleTableViewEditing()
        self.editEnabled()
        complete(true)

    }

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [edit])

}

func editEnabled() {
    if tableView.isEditing == true {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(toggleTableViewEditing))
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

@objc func toggleTableViewEditing() {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    editEnabled()
}
```

Once the edit button is tapped, the edit button dismisses but the tableview doesn't enter the .isEditing state like it should.

Comment: Please post your debug steps. You indicate `.isEditing` state not happening. So is `toggleTableViewEditing` actually happening? If so, is `editEnabled` working correctly? Or are you calling it after toggling the state?

Comment: This is a very unusual approach. Why not do what most apps do? Use the `UIViewController editButtonItem` button as the right bar button item. If this is a `UITableViewController` then that button automatically toggles the editing state of the table view. If you have a `UIViewController` with your own table view, override `setEditing(_:animated:)` to toggle the editing mode of the table view. Either way, implement the standard "move" related table view data source and delegate methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can use editActionsForRowAt function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, index) in
        // your edit action here
    }

    return [editAction]
}
```

I made an app like this and its work well.

Comment: How do I use this to show an edit swipe action, because just this on its own, does nothing when swiping

Comment: sorry dear , I forgot something ,you have to add this function: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }